# Обработка таймаутов через TcpClient

Tags: c#

Есть код:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
client.ReceiveTimeout = 60000; 

Byte[] data = new Byte[256];
String responseData = String.Empty;
Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);
```

Всё работает как часы, но нужно предусмотреть таймауты клиента. На MSDN я прочитал [статью TcpClient.ReceiveTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.receivetimeout(v=vs.110).aspx), и как я понял таймаут сработает следующим образом: клиент будет ждать ответа в течении 60 сек (мой случай, см. код) и потом будет просто пустой массив `data`. Никаких особых обработок таймаута для этого клиента не предусмотрено.

**Вопрос:**

То что я написал, это *мое мнение*, проверить не могу его. Может я не прав, и как-то следуют описывать таймаут для TcpClientа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На MSDN написано, что по истечении таймаута до успешного завершения метода `Read` объект `TcpClient` создает исключение `IOException`. Нужно обработать исключение.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сделал как-то так:

```
async Task<byte[]> ReadFromStreamAsync(NetworkStream s, uint nbytes, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var buf = new byte[nbytes];
    var readpos = 0;
    while (readpos < nbytes)
        readpos += await s.ReadAsync(buf, readpos, nbytes - readpos, ct);
    return buf;
}

async Task<byte[]> ReadWithTimeout(NetworkStream s, uint nbytes, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        var readTask = ReadFromStreamAsync(nbytes, cts.Token);
        var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeout);
        await Task.WhenAny(readTask, timeoutTask);
        if (!readTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            cts.Cancel(); // cancel read task
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            var bytes = readTask.Result;
            return Decode(bytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Не забудьте в случае таймаута закрыть `NetworkStream`.

---

Вот [это обсуждение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12422824/276994) советует ещё ловить `OperationCanceledException` для `readTask`.